# MvvmCross binding image file to Android ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, mvvmcross

I am trying to bind an image file to an Android ImageView that is within an MvxListView.  The images are just not appearing when the View is shown.

I have included the `MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.File` package.

ListVideo.axml (snippet)

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    local:MvxBind="ImageUrl Thumbnail" />
```

The typical value for Thumbnail is

```
VideoData/2015-07-24-09-26-16/2fea9249-9370-4542-927a-c856e678f7b1.jpg
```

The value of `Context.FilesDir.Path` is `/data/data/com.app.AppName/files`

The image file `/data/data/com.app.AppName/files/VideoData/2015-07-24-09-26-16/2fea9249-9370-4542-927a-c856e678f7b1.jpg` does exist

I understand that to bind an image some custom folder determined within your app, I need to provide a path relative to `Context.FilesDir.Path` in order for the plugin to load it.  I believe that the string in Thumbnail is correct.

But nothing is displayed in the ImageView. I have been banging my head against this one all morning.  Any suggestions?

Edit :

I have managed to solve the problem !!

I needed the `MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.DownloadCache` as well as the  `MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.File` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem !!

I needed the **`MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.DownloadCache`** as well as the **`MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.File`** package.